# Safari issue with table and table cell properties (responsive design)

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, zurb-foundation

First off I would like to start by explaining my issue, it is as follows:

In all browsers except for Safari my website http://www.hamiltonseniorcity.com/dean/location-category/health-wellness/?passedpageid=28&box=1 appears normal and scales down appropriately on this page, in Safari and on my iPad the page distorts and does not scale down to smaller screens properly. Also it appears that the div that holds the left and right content areas expands to full screen. I believe the issue is caused by how Safari is rendering my divs table and table cell properties, I could be wrong. Does anyone have a solution for this issue or any suggestions?

Comment: I've tested the page on Safari 6 under OS X and on my iPhone with iOS 6. It works fine - same result as in Chrome. Which version of the Safari Desktop and iOS are you using?

Comment: Did you look at it in another browser first? Also have you tried resizing it down to tablet size? I am using Safari Desktop 5.1.7 and iOS 6.1.3

Comment: I don't think there should be a problem in your code as you have done everything right in the given link!! then also if any problem comes divide div's  % and then it will do

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the page on the iPad and I can reproduce your problem.

The issue is caused by this CSS rule:

```
.equal-columns > div {
    display: table-row;
}
```

It's overwriting this code:

```
.equal-columns > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

with the help of this the media query addressing the iPad:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
```

I think Safari gets into trouble, as there's no table cell within the table row now. If you fix this and set it to `display: table-cell;` no matter what resolution, it works again in Safari on the iPad. I guess it will also fix it on the Safari 5.1.7 on PC.

---

Also note that Safari is no longer developed for PC. 5.1.7 is the latest and last release from May 2012. All the new Webkit stuff from Apple will not be available on PC. Unfortunately. …

Comment: Thanks for your assistance however unfortunately the layout seems to break out of its container after applying that fix. If you go to the url you will see this, also I need the right sidebar to go under the left side when scaled down to tablet or mobile. Any other suggestions?

Comment: anyone? I am completely stumped.